# How to get the equivalent of pg_dump -s <dbname> in Python (psycopg2)?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

My task is to compare the schemas of several databases in a cluster of our app in Postgres against the same databases of a different version of our app.

The comparison should only check the schema and not data.

The most basic way would be for me to use subproccess to execute

```
    pg_dump -U <user> -s <database> > schema.txt
```

for each database, then run a diff.

Two questions

1) Is this the right approach to see if the schema has changed?
2) Is this possible through psycopg2, without using subproccess or pg_dump or psql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what is meant by **if the schema has changed**. If that literally means if there's **any** difference at all between the schemas, no matter how significant, then yes, you would want to dump the schemas and then compare them.

For this task, you would definitely want to use `pg_dump` with the `--schema-only` option. There isn't an *SQL* statement that does this, so doing this directly via *psycopg2* isn't possible. (There are lower-level *Postgres* library functions that are available that allow programs like *PgAdmin3* to show all the *DDL* for tables and such, but I believe that would need to be called directly via *libpq*).

However, if what you want to find out is some other type of difference, it may be possible (if not somewhat more involved) to do it via *psycopg2* by querying the various [*system catalog*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html) tables.

For example, you could query [pg_tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-tables.html) to determine what tables are present, and compare those to see if any are missing. You could then query those tables directly to get more information, say, to check to see if the counts are the same, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've basically come to the same conclusion and will be using pg_dumpall -s. The question now is how to properly compare 2 50k lines files which may not be in the same order.

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you run into issues with the compare, feel free to post a new question for that. I have some thoughts on how that could perhaps be done.